# I somehow made our linux box's "CP" command act differently than the default, how can I revert it back to default?

Tags: linux, cp, default-settings

Title explains it;

Somehow in installing the 'z' directory jumper, I made our linux machines CP command act strangely (for example: it no longer prompts for overwrites, it auto-forces it whether we want it or not) - does anybody know how to revert my linux box's CP command back to its default setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux `cp` does not, by default, prompt you when overwriting. If it used to, then as @mirkobrankovic said, it was most likely defined as an [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

User specific aliases are usually in `~/.bashrc` and global aliases are in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You probably had an alias in one of those files that turned `cp` into `cp -i` if you were asked before overwriting.

To set up that alias again, add this line to either of the two files I mentioned above:

```
alias cp='cp -i'
```

The alias will take effect next time you open a terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

On modern linux systems, `cp` no longer prompts to overwrite file.
If it used to do that before, than you probably lost an alias. 
Add

```
alias cp='cp -i'
```

at the end of  or `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Logout and log back in console to take effect.